# Writing user input to a .txt file (Python 3)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been working on this student grade calculator for a few weeks and now have been told I need the names/grades written to a .txt file, I have used user input for this project and I am now struggling to collect the data and store it into a file. Hoping someone can set me on the right path here is my code...

```
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
    Number_Of_Numbers = int(input("How many students do you want to add? "))
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
    Numbers_To_Be_Added = []
    for i in range(Number_Of_Numbers):
        print ('Please enter your name')
        str1 = (input())  
        print ('Please enter your grade')
        Number = float(input())
        print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
        while Number <0 or Number >= 101:  
           print("Error")
           print ('Please enter your grade')
           Number = float(input())
           print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
           if Number >= 0 and Number <= 100:
              break
        Numbers_To_Be_Added.append(Number)
        total = sum(Numbers_To_Be_Added)
        if i == Numbers_To_Be_Added:
          break
        average = (total /Number_Of_Numbers)
    print ("The Average is: ","{0:.3f}".format(average))
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")
    print("Goodbye!")
    print("---------------------------------------------------------------")

    with open('Results.txt','w') as f:
        f.write('')
```

As you can see I have the function to write to a file I'm just not sure how to collect data from the user input.

Comment: It looks like you barely tried. What is your main issue? Where is your stack trace?

Comment: It's the first program I've ever written, been using Python for like 3 month.. got told this was a good website first reply I get is that^

Comment: Here is your problem: you gather the input and then print it right away. Don't do that; *store* it somewhere, just like you do with `Numbers_To_Be_Added`, and write that bulk to the file. The `if` test is weird? Comparing an index to a list. Lose it. Also, I'm not convinced of the place of `average`. You *calculate* it per student but *print* it only on e.

Comment: You either need to write out the data immediately as you receive it, before you throw away that info, or need to hold onto all of that info until it’s time to write. For example, you can’t write out the name of each student if the only place you stored it was the `str1` variable that you then just replaced with the next student’s name. But you can write it out inside the loop, while you still have it, or you could keep the student names inside your list of info instead of discarding them.

Comment: @usr2564301 +abarnet Both of them replies are really helpful. I have went with storing the names/grades into separate lists and then writing them to the file. can't thank you enough

Answer (score -1):

There are some ways to write data in a file

To rewrite a .txt file:

```
file = open("any_file_name.txt", "w")
file.write("info")
```

To append to a .txt file:

```
file = open("any_file_name.txt", "a")
file.write("info")
```

Of course after inputting data, you will want to receive it back

To read the .txt file, put some sort of separator like "#" and "\n":

```
file = open("any_file_name.txt", "r")
all_the_data = []
for line in file:
    one_piece_of_data = line.split("#")[0]
    all_the_data.append(one_piece_of_data)
# now all the data is in the variable!
```